# How do I connect a buzzer to GPIO?

Tags: gpio

I have a [PS1240P02BT](http://www.tdk.co.jp/tefe02/ef532_ps.pdf) piezzo-electric buzzer. I want to drive it with a software generated 3.3V 4KHz square wave from one of the GPIOS.

What kind of resistor do I need between the buzzer and the GND pin?

I know practically nothing about electronics, so could you please explain like I'm five?

Comment: How are you generating the 4kHz in software? I think you'll need to use the pwm, otherwise every few cycles the tone will be interrupted when the process is preempted.

Comment: I don't think a couple millisecond interruption will be noticeable.

Comment: It will be noticeable for sure. Whether it's important for your application or not is a different question

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a recommended circuit on page 7 of [the data sheet](http://www.tdk.co.jp/tefe02/ef532_ps.pdf)

The transistor isn't critical, any small [NPN](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bipolar_junction_transistor#NPN) should work fine.

1000 ohm should be ok for both resistors

> **NPN** is one of the two types of bipolar transistors, consisting of a
>   layer of P-doped semiconductor (the "base") between two N-doped
>   layers. A small current entering the base is amplified to produce a
>   large collector and emitter current. That is, when there is a positive
>   potential difference measured from the emitter of an NPN transistor to
>   its base (i.e., when the base is high relative to the emitter) as well
>   as positive potential difference measured from the base to the
>   collector, the transistor becomes active. In this "on" state, current
>   flows between the collector and emitter of the transistor. Most of the
>   current is carried by electrons moving from emitter to collector as
>   minority carriers in the P-type base region. To allow for greater
>   current and faster operation, most bipolar transistors used today are
>   NPN because electron mobility is higher than hole mobility.

Comment: For clarification could you please spell out the acronym for NPN?

Comment: @tkeE2036, It's not an [acronym](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Acronym), it's a type of transistor. Roughly speaking "A layer of P-doped semiconductor between two N-doped layers." But that's not helpful if you don't know what "N-doped" and "P-doped" mean. It's usually much more useful to know _what_ and NPN transistor _is_, without worrying about what NPN stands for.